# moving particle submitted to a law of motion

Tags: calculus

I understand everything up to the point when the particle is moving in the positive direction.  I know that I need to take the velocity at time t and set it to be greater than 0 and find out during what time interval my velocity is greater than 0.

In my calculus class, we went over how to do it with an equation which could easily be factored, but this equation isn't one that can be easily factored.

What I initially did was set the equation of the derivative to be greater than 0, then subtracted 20 from both sides.  Then I factored out a t from the left side and got: $t(3t - 14) > -20$

I set $(3t - 14) > -20$  and got the answer $t < -2$
and $t > 20$.  But, there is where I'm getting stuck.  I've been looking at this for over an hour right now and I'm still not getting it.  Can someone help me see where I am going wrong?

[This is a picture of the problem I am working on regarding a particle moving according to a law of motion.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3QAN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting $t>20$ (correct answer indeed) and writing an interval that does not represent this value. Check that the interval must be$ (-∞,-2)$U$(20,∞)$